# "Take the weight off your feet": offensive?

Tags: meaning, politeness

I kind of have the impression that the phrase, "take the weight off your feet," is offensive towards *fat* people (sorry couldn't think of any **PC** terms).

Is my impression correct? or have I just watched too many sitcoms?

[I did try googling this - but came up with nothing!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never run into anyone who would consider it offensive (whether phrased that way, or simply as "take a load off"). And that would have included myself when I was on the wrong side of 280 lbs (I'm about 135 lbs now, and the extra wasn't muscle). You'd be just as likely to use it when speaking to someone who you might describe as *svelte* if they weren't so skinny, unless you intend it as an insult. It's simply an invitation to sit (and usually implies an invitation to be casual as well).